# Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create an application that has user profiles like in the following (the first image): https://dribbble.com/shots/1642506-Messaging-app-Viber/attachments/257232

I am particularly interested in the bottom part of the profile, under the white line and the "FOLLOW ME" section. My assumption is that this is done using a UICollectionView, but please correct me if I am mistaken, and I will edit this question accordingly. For 6 elements, the collection view looks pretty standard (where 'o' represents a circle):
o o o
o o o

I do not want them to be laid out as such for every number lower than 6. I want them to be centered. For example, 5 elements would look like:
o o o
 o o --> (centered between the top three - Markdown whitespace)

4:
 o o
 o o

3:
o o or o o o (probably former, empty bottom line looks messy)
 o --> (centered between the top two - Markdown whitespace)

2:
 o
 o

1:
 o

If you have any better layout suggestions, please let me know. So, as you can see from above, I want the layout to change based on the number of elements in the data source of the collection view. The number of elements will never exceed 6.

Additionally, the user might be able to edit one of these profiles, in which a '+' icon will appear, making the collection view appear with the (n+1) layout. For example, a user editing a profile with 4 elements will look at a collection view layout as if it had 5 elements, the fifth one being a '+' sign to add another element. A user will only be able to delete elements from a profile that already has 6 elements.

Initially, I was thinking of using a bunch of 'if' and 'switch' statements based on the indexPath.row of the collection view and the number of elements in the data source. But, that seems sloppy. Is there a way to do this using a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout? Either way, how would one go about implementing such a layout?

Thanks for any advice in advance. Sorry that this question is long, and I can provide clarification wherever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a collection view is the wrong solution. They're designed to show an arbitrary amount of content in a scrolling grid or other procedural layout. You have 1-6 buttons with an aesthetic layout that isn't easy to produce from an algorithm.

Really, you have 10 "slots" in a 5x2 arrangement that you want to place the buttons in:

```
[01234]
[56789]
```

All you need to do is generate those positions programmatically, then define your layouts as arrays of "slots":

6 Items: `@[0,2,4,5,7,9]`

5 Items: `@[0,2,4,6,8]`

And so on...

Comment: If a collection view is not the right solution, what do you suggest? I feel like the only other alternative is to have a bunch of cascading 'if' and 'switch' statements, which could get ugly with all the magic numbers for the different positions. @joshua-sullivan